If I upgrade Windows 11 Home OEM version to Windows 11 Pro then will upgraded version be a retail version?
I have a laptop which has preinstalled from manufacturer preinstalled Windows 11 Home. I want to upgrade it to the Windows 11 Pro version.
If I do so will Windows 11 Pro be Retail version?

@Gantendo I can transfer Retail to any other hardware but not OEM.

“If I do so will Windows 11 Pro be Retail version?” - Only if you use a retail license

@JW0914 COA stickers haven’t contained a product key for quite some time now. The embedded key is unique but cannot be used on other machines.

@JW0914 - “Microsoft requires all OEMs to provide a CoA sticker with an actual product key that can be used to activate Windows” - This hasn’t been true since the release of Windows 8 back in 2012. The sticker is required but the license key is no longer printed on the sticker itself.

Microsoft license terms cover this particular case and are very clear:


Transfer. The provisions of this section do not apply if you acquired the software in Germany or in any of the countries listed on this site https://aka.ms/transfer, in which case any transfer of the software to a third party, and the right to use it, must comply with applicable law.
a. Software preinstalled on device. If you acquired the software preinstalled on a device (and also if you upgraded from software preinstalled on a device), you may transfer the license to use the software directly to another user, only with the licensed device. The transfer must include the software and, if provided with the device, an authentic Windows label including the product key. Before any permitted transfer, the other party must agree that this agreement applies to the transfer and use of the software.



(Emphasis mine)
No, you cannot “free” your Windows license by upgrading to Pro.

According to the Microsoft article
Upgrade Windows Home to Windows Pro,
this upgrade is done simply by entering the Pro serial number via
Settings > System > Activation > Change product key,
and Windows will do all the required installation work.
Once the activation is finished, your Windows will be activated as
Retail. You will be able to transfer the Pro serial number to other
computers, after disabling it in this computer.
Note that according to Microsoft's
Windows upgrade paths,
downgrading back to Home once you remove the Pro key is much more
serious and will remove all applications and settings.
